# Java Android SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sqlite

I have a problem with one of my first Android application.

I created SQLiteDatabase in Main activity.

```
   private SQLiteDatabase db = null;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    }
    //DatabaseHelper only creates Table and puts some initial values
```

But I want to access this db from my another acivity. (AddItem activity).

I don't know, how to do this, and if it's possible.

Thank you for your answers.. :)

Comment: discussed in detail here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905846/android-accessing-single-database-from-multiple-activities-in-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
```

Is a big mistake - You're creating an anonymous helper, while you need the exact opposite - to cherish this instance and use it everywhere. The writable database is something to create and dispose many many times during the life of your app.

You need to keep the helper as a singleton.
You can use this piece of code I wrote for my own use. Place it inside your helper class.

The helper is created lazily - not necessarily in onCreate().
You can than use it from any activity and from any thread (it's thread safe).

```
    private static DbHelperAndroid mInstance = null;

public static DbHelperAndroid getDb(Context ctx) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        synchronized (TAG) { // any final static object will do
            // checking again inside the sync block, since it's a critical section.
            // I'm not doing this in the above if because it's really rare
            // and I don't want the overhead of locks all the time
            if (mInstance == null) {
                mInstance = new DbHelperAndroid(
                        ctx.getApplicationContext(), true);
            }
        }

    }
    return mInstance;
}
```

Comment: Okey, I've made static Databasehelper in my main activity, then I want to try to access it in AddItem activity, and it's okey. Thank you for your answer...now I have a different problem to solve :D

Comment: Fully working ;) Thanks one more time ;)

Comment: Excellent! now you can accept the answer

Comment: ..just noticed you wrote the static helper is in your main activity.  You should put it in the helper class, because you want it from *any* activity.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be letting your custom class implement Serializable interface and then you can pass object instances in intent extra using putExtra(Serializable..) variant of the Intent#putExtra() method.

PSEUDO code:

//to pass :
   intent.putExtra("dbtag", db);

// to retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("dbtag");

Comment: This one says, that putExtra (String, SQLiteDatabase) doesn't exist.. :/

Answer (score 0):

MySQL database, that was created in main_activity is accessible from other activities too.
Just use

```
// SQLiteDatabase db_name = db_name.getWritableDatabase();
```

in other activity, and you can work with it.

Don't forget to close it after

Comment: This one is not workin, I can't call method getWritableDatabase to db_name ....:(